# cannot import resource in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony2. I am designing a form.

My action for submission is task_new. And my routing.yml is as follows:

```
task:
    pattern:   /task/
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeTaskBundle:Task:new}
task_new:
     defaults:{_controller:AcmeTaskBundle:Task:sub}
```

I want that after submission the form it should go to sub action. when i am running this code I am getting the following error:

> Cannot import resource "C:\wamp\www\Symfony\src\Acme\TaskBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" from "C:/wamp/www/Symfony/app/config\routing.yml".

What should I do?

Comment: Isn't the pattern parameter required for the 'task_new' route?

Comment: The error message tells you that Symfony can't find the routing.yml file supposed to be in the src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/config/ folder. Is the file there?

Comment: Have you tried with: resource: "@AcmeTaskBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml" (backslashes instead of slashes) in the app.config/routing.yml file?

Comment: @Marronsuisse yep when i am doing this then i am getting new error  Cannot import resource "@AcmeTaskBundle\Resources\config outing.yml" from "C:/wamp/www/Symfony/app/config\routing.yml". Make sure the "AcmeTaskBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such error usually appears when you have error in your resource file.
In your case - I guess, you missed the `pattern` for `task_new` route

Also check if `defaults` starts right after **4** spaces from the beginning

```
task_new:
    defaults: { _controller:AcmeTaskBundle:Task:sub }
```

Comment: when i am using pattern for task_new then also i am getting the same problem

Comment: It looks like defaults:{_controller:AcmeTaskBundle:Task:sub} has extra whitespace at the beginning. Yaml is very sensitive to formatting. Could you also check this?

Comment: task:
    pattern:   \task\
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeTaskBundle:Task:new}
task_new:
    pattern: \task_new\
    defaults: {_controller:AcmeTaskBundle:Task:sub} now i am doing this then a new error is : No route found for "GET /task/"

Comment: You should use normal slash, not backslash :)

Comment: thanx to all guys i have solved the problems. thanx for support